# How to convert cURL to libcurl(c)

Tags: curl, libcurl

I have the following cmd and its work.
- using digest auth
- using json data

```
curl -v --digest -u user:passwd -X POST http://192.168.139.65:80/digest/getMode -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"Data":{}}'
```

I would like to convert cURL to libcurl.

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://192.168.139.65:80/digest/getMode");
headerlist = curl_slist_append(headerlist, "Content-Type: application/json");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headerlist);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_DIGEST);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user:passwd ");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"Data\":\t{}\r\n}");

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
```

But I got fail, It return 401. Is there any missing? Thanks for help

Comment: Your options seem correct. However, you have a space after "passwd". Should it not be "user:passwd" instead of "user:passwd "? Also, I believe that using `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` is redundant - as using `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` should automatically set the request type to `POST`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Finally, I check the message different between two method. I found that `TCP_NODELAY` and `USERAGENT` used in cURL. I need to add these two command.

Comment: It's rather rude to accept your own (totally wrong) answer when @jodh above actually gave you the correct one.

Answer (score 4):

Just add `--libcurl -filename.c` after your curl command. This will create a C source file performing the exact same operation as your curl command.